# When UIView height set zero, view's child control not hide

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I want drawer animation. So I take 1 UIView and add 4 control inside UIView.
Now when I click on drawer button, set view height zero when drawer is close and set view height 200 when drawer is open.

But **when I set zero height, button is not hide . All buttons are visible.**
Auto layout  is not in my project.

How to solved this problem.?

```
-(IBAction)Onclick_drawer:(id)sender
{
    if(is_open)
    {
        is_open=false;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.0
             usingSpringWithDamping:1.0
              initialSpringVelocity:4.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{

                             self.drawer_view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 64, 320,200);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         }];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    else
    {
        is_open=true;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.0
             usingSpringWithDamping:1.0
              initialSpringVelocity:4.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             self.drawer_view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 0);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         }];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks @EI Captain 
My Problem is solved. TYSM

Answer (score 20, accepted):

check in xib ... `select view -> attribute inspector -> check clip Subviews` like below image

[image]

or programatically use

```
   self.yourview.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: You saved my day ! <3

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot glad it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Just select the view and go to right side of screen into **attribute inspector**

Check the check box for `Clip Subviews`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)Onclick_drawer:(id)sender
{
    if(is_open)
    {
        is_open=false;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.0
             usingSpringWithDamping:1.0
              initialSpringVelocity:4.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{

                             self.drawer_view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 64, 320,200);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         }];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    else
    {
        is_open=true;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                              delay:0.0
             usingSpringWithDamping:1.0
              initialSpringVelocity:4.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             self.drawer_view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 0);
                             self.drawer_view.clipsToBounds = YES;  // Need to add this line. This will clip all sub views into parent view 
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         }];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }


}
```